# Can't get NetSNMP agent to answer using my prorietary MIB

Tags: perl, snmpd, oid

I have to add a proprietary MIB to debian's snmpd that I must be able to query (get and set) from another networked computer on a non-standard UDP port (network aspects will be a further step).

I have a MIB file in `~/.snmp/mibs` and a perl extension for the agent, that is currently very close to what I could find on the Net. I have modiified the `/etc/default/snmp`, `/etc/snmp/snmp.conf` and `/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf` as understood from various tutorials

SNMP v3 is a constraint so I have created a user following the tutorials available on the Net.

Everything works when I query for example `sysUpTime.0`. But I cannot access my private MIB:

- snmpget says "No Suvh Instance currently exists at this OID" but can give me the name
- snmpwalk gives an empy content for the MIB when I ask from the top of my private MIB
- snmptranslate says "Unknown Object Identifier (Sub-id not found)"

I don't know if this is sufficient a description for someone to help me. My current belief is that the agent does not know how to answer, but I can't seem to be able to find what prevents it from doing so (the perl sub-agent is registered as read in the tutorials).

The only things I know about SNMP (apart from various interpretations of the acronym, and the fact that once you've understood how it works it 'seems' simple) is what I have found the last days on the Net. thus please forgive if I don't always use the most appropriate terms. Network-wise I am rather a user, other than that I usually develop low-level drivers.

Thanks a lot for any help

Daniel

Comment: Did you restart SNMPD after modifying the configurations?

Comment: You not only need your own mib (and please ask for you own enterprise id with IANA), you need to tell snmpd what to do when it gets a request for this OID. Read the section "EXTENDING AGENT FUNCTIONALITY" in snmpd.conf man page.